# How to use dynamic types conforming to protocols

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just trying to get a grasp as to why this isn't possible. Why can I not use a dynamic type with this setup. (I put this in playgrounds):

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    init()
}

class SomeClass : SomeProtocol {
    required init() { }
}

let x: SomeProtocol.Type = SomeClass.self

x()
```

When this runs, playgrounds will crash, and if you try to put code like this in Xcode it will throw a

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

If I, however, never call `x()`, I can print out x to be of the correct SomeClass.Type.

I realize this is a weird setup, so I understand the confusion of "why would you ever want to do that?". But that aside; is it possible? not possible? Is it a bug? Am  I not understanding how protocols really work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine. I tried your code in Xcode 7 and it compiles and runs. Of course, in real code you can't say `x()` at top level. And in Swift 2 you have to say `x.init()`, not `x()`. But when you do, it's fine.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    init()
}
class SomeClass : SomeProtocol {
    required init() { }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let x: SomeProtocol.Type = SomeClass.self
        x.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, don't test this kind of thing in a playground. Playgrounds are the work of the devil.

Comment: I'll have to try everything in Xcode 7, I'm in 6 right now. And I didn't really test it in playgrounds, I ran into it in Xcode and decided putting it in playgrounds would be the easiest way to communicate it and change things.

Comment: A lot of weird things you'll encounter with protocols in Swift 1.2 are bugs that are fixed in Swift 2.0.

Comment: @matt Currently in XCode 7 beta 6, this line only gives a runtime error in playground: `[1, 2, 3][1...1]`